# Fabricjs does not clone strokeUniform property

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Fabricjs does not copy strokeUniform property when I clone objects, even if I use the `propertiesToInclude` parameter.

```
obj.clone( function ( cloned ) {
    console.log(cloned.strokeUniform) // --> always false
}, [ 'strokeUniform' ] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this trick

```
obj.clone(function(cloned) {
    cloned.strokeUniform = obj.strokeUniform
});
```